# send email to a bunch of users class

Tags: php

```
class emailer
{
private $sender;
private $recipients;
private $subject;
private $body;
function __construct($sender)
{
$this->sender = $sender;
$this->recipients = array();
}
public function addRecipients($recipient)
{
array_push($this->recipients, $recipient);
}
public function setSubject($subject)
{
$this->subject = $subject;
}
public function setBody($body)
{
$this->body = $body;
}
public function sendEmail()
{
foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
{
$result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body,
"From: {$this->sender}\r\n");
if ($result) echo "Mail successfully sent to
{$recipient}<br/>";
}
}
}
```

why the code write this function?

```
function __construct($sender)
    {
    $this->sender = $sender;
    $this->recipients = array();
    }
```

could i delete it? thank you.

Comment: The code wrote that function?  Or you wrote that function?  Where did you get this code if you didn't write it?  That function is a constructor.  You can delete it if you don't want to have a constructor that accepts a sender, sets the sender to that parameter, and initializes the recipients array.

Comment: the code id from a book, i am new to object programming, could you give me more details.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to the question...

That function is called a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).  Take a look at its form:

```
function __construct($sender)
{
  $this->sender = $sender;
  $this->recipients = array();
}
```

Walking through what it's doing, the first thing you see is that it has a standardized name.  In this case, `__construct` is reserved by the language to specify that this function is used to build an instance of an object described by this class.

Next, note that it accepts a parameter.  This means that when you create an instance of the class, you'd supply that instance with a parameter.  So when you create an instance, you'd do something like this:

```
$obj = new emailer($someSender);
```

What you're doing here is creating an instance of `emailer` and supplying it a `sender` parameter.  This call to `new` is what invokes the constructor.  (Essentially, it's "constructing" a "new" instance of `emailer`.)

Internal to the constructor, it's doing two things:

1. Set the `sender` property on the object to the `$someSender` which was provided in the call to `new`.
2. Initialize the `recipients` property to a new array.

Finally, note that this function doesn't return anything.  It's a standardized function reserved by the language, and an implication is that what it's "returning" is a new instance of that class.  In the example call above, this instance is being set to `$obj`.

Comment: many thanks.but i still don't know why i should write the  constructor to the programming by myself. if i write the  programming.maybe i will omit it.

Comment: @zhuanzhou: It's a useful function to have because it's a single place to perform object construction logic.  In this particular case, for example, this constructor is initializing an array within the object.  If you didn't have that, then any time you create an instance of the object you'd have to manually initialize that array.  The constructor is a single place to do that.  It gets even more flexible and powerful when you define multiple constructors to accept different parameter sets, set different object defaults, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is called an [constuctor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), and it is made so that one can easily initialize an emailer object just using this method (by writing new then class name, then the constuctor arguments).

Example:

```
//One can use the constructor to create a new emailer
$emailer = new emailer("example@example.com");
//Do something with emailer ...
```